# How do I backup my Borderlands Character?

Tags: steam, borderlands

I need to reinstall my operating system. How do I back up my progress and character in Borderlands?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Backup your save files and place them back in the same location.  They are in

```
My Documents >> My Games >> Borderlands >> SaveData
```

Comment: If you manually copy your save games note one thing. The saveslot used by the save is NOT tied to the name of the save. Savegame01 renamed to savegame02 WILL overwrite savegame01 upon saving. Lost a character that way.

Answer (score 5):

As of Sept 9, 2011, a [Borderlands Steam update](http://store.steampowered.com/news/6232/) was released to transfer saved games to the cloud, meaning that the saved progress and characters would be restored after your operating system reinstall.